# Is it possible to use spike-ins with droplet technologies?

Tags: scrnaseq, spike-in

By reading Bacher & Kendziorski (2016), I found the following statement:

> recent droplet technologies are not yet able to accommodate spike-ins

What's the reason why current droplet technologies cannot use spike-ins? By searching through the available methodologies I found [this question](https://community.10xgenomics.com/t5/Single-Cell-Forum/Thoughts-on-ERCC-Spike-Ins/td-p/207) on 10X community, but still I cannot understand what is the problem created by using spike-ins with droplet technologies.

1. Bacher, R. & Kendziorski, C. [Design and computational analysis of single-cell RNA-sequencing experiments](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4823857/). Genome Biol. 17, 63 (2016).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is mostly a cost issue as spike-ins are "expensive" to use given the large number of cells that are/can be sequenced via droplet based methods (as compared to plate-based ones). The 10x link that you provided actually states that this is possible with 10x and Klein et al. used ERCC spike-ins in 953 droplets (Cell. 2015 May 21;161(5):1187-1201. doi: 10.1016/j.cell.2015.04.044.).